# element.parentNode.removeChild() method not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-9

I am trying `element.parentNode.removeChild()` method. Its working fine in Firefox but not working in IE 9.

Can anyone please tell how to remove an element in IE using javascript?

Thanks...

Comment: Please paste your code and exact error you r getting.

Comment: Go through this.worth a read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild

Comment: @nyan, Thanks for your comment. I will post my code soon. right now I do not have access to my code.

Comment: @ubercooluk , thanks for link. That explains how to remove child node correctly.

Comment: Can anyone explain why my question is down voted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `removeChild` function in the parentNode of the element.

If `element` is the node that needs to be removed, then do this:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Comment: is it possible to use `this` on this example?